# How to iterate over column values in a dataframe, take the mean, and create a new dataframe?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, mean

I have a large dataframe in R and I want to plot the change in temperature over time. I've tried this before but since there is so much data the graph is really noisy and impossible to read.

I experimented with other plot types to try and get around this but they didn't really work. So I decided instead I will plot the mean temperature for each hour.

I've uploaded the data from a csv file and there are about 56k rows, an hour is about 720 rows give or take.

```
> head(wormData)
 Time     Date Day.of.Week Humidity.1 Temp.1 Vapor.Density.1 Base.Temp.1
1 0:18:44 1/7/2016      Friday       69.7   26.4           17.43       85.00
2 0:18:49 1/7/2016      Friday       69.7   26.4           17.43       27.44
3 0:18:54 1/7/2016      Friday       69.6   26.4           17.40       27.44
4 0:18:59 1/7/2016      Friday       69.6   26.4           17.40       27.44
5 0:19:05 1/7/2016      Friday       69.5   26.4           17.38       27.44
6 0:19:10 1/7/2016      Friday       69.5   26.4           17.38       27.44
```

The column I am interested in is Temp.1 so what I want to do is take the mean of every 720 values in the Temp.1 column, then put each of those mean values into a new dataframe so I can plot a cleaner graph.

I thought of just doing it by hand but that would be about 50 data points and I have many more csv files to do, so any help on how I could do this would be appreciated. I've tried subsetting the data or making vectors with the mean values as well as writing some loops, but I'm struggling to tell R that I want the mean of every 720 rows.

Thanks so much :)

Comment: You could also extract the hour from the `Time` variable with `format` and use that as a grouping variable, see `?strptime` for the specific codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A kind of basic solution on top of `matrix`:

```
 set.seed(123)
 x<-sample(1:10,(720*5),replace=TRUE) # generate dummy data

 > str(x)
 int [1:3600] 3 8 5 9 10 1 6 9 6 5 ...

 # Use wormData$Temp.1 instead of x for your actual datas  
 z<-matrix(x,nrow=length(x)/719) # divide by 719 to get 720 values per row
 rowMeans(z) # 'loop' over each row to get the mean
```

Output:

```
[1] 5.654167 5.375000 5.358333 5.477778 5.618056
```

If your dataset is not a multiple of 720, you'll get a warning and the last point would be false (recycling of the vector to fill the last line).

Comment: Thank you very much I understand the logic behind it now :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `dplyr`, assuming your row number is a multiple of 720. We create a grouping variable and then compute the mean by group.

```
library(dplyr)
n <- 2 # replace with n <- 720 with your actual data
mutate(d,group = rep(1:(nrow(d)/n), each=n)) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarize(mean=mean(Temp.1))
```

### data

```
d <- read.table(text = " Time     Date Day.of.Week Humidity.1 Temp.1 Vapor.Density.1 Base.Temp.1
1 0:18:44 1/7/2016      Friday       69.7   26.4           17.43       85.00
2 0:18:49 1/7/2016      Friday       69.7   26.4           17.43       27.44
3 0:18:54 1/7/2016      Friday       69.6   26.4           17.40       27.44
4 0:18:59 1/7/2016      Friday       69.6   26.4           17.40       27.44
5 0:19:05 1/7/2016      Friday       69.5   26.4           17.38       27.44
6 0:19:10 1/7/2016      Friday       69.5   26.4           17.38       27.44",stringsAsFactor=FALSE,head=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more complete answer using `dplyr`. This uses the actual dates and times you have so that you aren't approximating 720 values per hour.

```
library(tidyverse)

worm_data <- data_frame(time = c("0:18:44","0:18:49","2:18:54",
                                 "0:18:59","0:19:05","2:19:10"),
                        date = c("2016-07-01","2016-07-01","2016-07-01", 
                                 "2016-07-02", "2016-07-02", "2016-07-02"),
                        temp_1 = c(25,27,290,30,20,2))

worm_data_test <- worm_data %>%
   mutate(
      date = paste(date, time),
      date = as.POSIXct(date, tz="GMT", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
   ) %>%
   group_by(
      datetime = as.POSIXct(cut(date, breaks='hour')) # creates a new variable
   ) %>%
   summarize(
      temp_1 = mean(temp_1, na.rm=T)
   ) %>%
   ungroup()
```

In this case, you are grouping by the hour, then summarizing over those hours. I chose strange values and modified the dates and times to show that it works.

For more on datetime, I suggest: https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/dates.html